# Nodemon install warning on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, nodemon

I am trying to install nodemon on a Virtual Machine running Linux, but am getting a few warnings which I cannot work out how to resolve.

I am in the home directory, and running the command:

```
npm install nodemon
```

This attempts to install, but I am getting some warnings at the bottom:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/lancs/shearer/package.json'
npm WARN shearer No description
npm WARN shearer No repository field.
npm WARN shearer No README data
npm WARN shearer No license field.
```

I assume that this is causing the installation to then terminate, as when I try and run the command:

```
nodemon -v
```

afterwards, I am getting the message that the command could not be found.

Could anyone help me resolve this, I am unsure if the process of installing nodemon is different on linux than I have previously done on MacOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things happening here, neither of which is actually an error:

1. NPM will look for your module's `package.json` file when you run `npm install`. If it can't find it, it'll give you some warnings (in particular "can't open file" and "missing field" warnings, like you get). Warnings *don't* abort the installation, only errors do, and the installation likely did complete successfully.
2. You installed `nodemon` locally, which means you can't just run `nodemon` to start it (since it only looks for globaly installed programs by default). To install globally, run `npm install -g nodemon`, or run it locally with `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon` (if you are currently in your module's root directory).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and helping me understand the difference between local and global installation. The second part of your answer has worked and I can now see the version. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I executed command `npm install -g nodemon` on linux, i got a error and some warnings, then i executed `sudo npm install -g nodemon` and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing globally? You may want to run `npm install -g nodemon`

Comment: I was not installing globally, my problem is fixed now - thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. As a rule of thumb, if you run it in the terminal, include the global tag, but if you require it, don't use the global tag. See this article for more informaion : https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/